# Why does having groups where order of domain doesn't divide order of co-domain imply that a group homomorphism must be trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The statement I am seeing in a lot of proofs has that if we have some homomorphism between a group G and a group H, say

```
f:G -> H
```

Where the order of G does not divide the order of H, then the homomorphism must be trivial, but why is this the case?  I think I've seen proofs that involved G and H being cyclic groups, but what about in a more general case?

Comment: $|G|=|Kernel|\cdot|Image|$

Comment: the order of $\mathbb Z_4$ does not divide the order of $\mathbb Z_2$, but isn't there a non-trivial homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_4$ to $\mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: I think you want the order of $G$ and $H$ to be coprime, and then J.W.Tanner's comment above applies.